# add action in ignited datatables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Ignited Datatables for viewing active users. What I want now is to have an Action column which I can disable the user. This is my code.

view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users_table').dataTable({
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/users/get_active_users",
        "sServerMethod": "POST",
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [7]
        }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
<thead>
  <tr>
     <th class="width70 text-center">Username</th>
     <th class="text-center">Full Name</th>
     <th class="text-center">Office</th>
     <th class="text-center">Position</th>
     <th class="text-center">Email</th>
     <th class="width60 text-center">Privilege</th>
     <th class="width160 text-center">Date Registered</th>
     <th class="width60 text-center">Actions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">Loading data from server</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with using ignited datatables you need to add action column in your datatables like

```
$this->datatables->add_column('action', '<a href="user/disable/$1">Disable User</a>', id);
```

Comment: yes.
there's a small typo in your code id should be inside the quote